# C guessing game using while loops to limit user guesses and isdigit for verification

Tags: c, while-loop

**Task:**

- Create a number guessing game where the user has a limited number of guesses to figure out what the randomly generated number is
- Check whether the user has inputted a digit or character using "Isdigit" informing them to input a number between 1 and 20 if they use the wrong input or guess out of the expected range.
- Using a while loop limits the user guesses
- After the user runs out of guesses close the program

**Problem I'm facing:** I'm new to programming and so I don't have too much experience yet. It's my first time trying to understand the is digit function and I feel like there is a more efficient way of solving this problem.

- Since I'm using 2 data types when trying to compare int's and chars I can't make a direct comparison but I figured out the difference between char 1 and int 1 is 48 apart so I made that as a temporary solution. But it only works for single-digit numbers
- I've read that I might be able to go through the string character by character to make sure each of them are a digit before the input is accepted and combine the string at the end but I'm not sure how to do that
- The user can't input more than 1 character or the program ends
- I'd also like to fix any other bugs people may find and write the code in a more effective and understandable way

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int iRandomNum = 5;         //setting up a number as a placeholder until Code works
        char guess;                 //char being used as I beleive it needs to be char for isdigit to function
        int guessCount = 0;         //
        int guessLimit = 3;
        int outOfGuess = 0;
    
        srand(1-10);
        //iRandomNum = (rand()%20)+1;
        while (guess != iRandomNum && guessCount != 3 && outOfGuess == 0){  //Intended to break out of loop once any variable is satisfied
            if(guessCount< guessLimit){
                    printf("\n%d", iRandomNum);
                    printf("\nYou have %d guesses left", guessLimit- guessCount);   //extra user info
                    printf("\nGuess the number between 1 - 10: ");
                    scanf(" %s", &guess);
    
                if (isdigit(guess)==0)
                    {
                        printf("\nEnter a digit!");
                        guessCount++;               //supposed to limit user to 3 chances
                    }else
                    {         //need help solving this
                        printf("\nYou entered %d\n", guess - 48); //Using for testing
                        guess = guess - 48;
                        if (guess == iRandomNum)       //I dont think functions as char and int are different data types
                        {
                            printf("\nYou've Won");
                            break;
                        }else{
                            printf("\nWrong guess");
                            guessCount++;
                            }
                    }
    
            }else        //Once user runs out of guesses while loop should break an then display following data
                {
                    printf("Second else");
                    guessCount++;
                    //outOfGuess = 1;
                }
            }
    
        if (outOfGuess == 1){
            printf("\nOut of guesses!");
        }
        else{
            printf("\nCongratulations!");
        }
        return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: `scanf(" %s", &guess);` is incorrect, `"%s"` is for strings, you want `" %c"` for `char`s.

Comment: _Task_ would be greatly simplified if you didn't have to use `isdigit`, and instead went directly to `strtol` -- you don't really care why the input is not a number if it is not a number.

Comment: IMO `if (scanf("%d", &myIntGuess) == 1) { ... }` would be the most straight-forward way to go about this, but OP says using `isdigit` is a requirement.

Comment: `'0'` would be better then `48` for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue not already mentioned in comments: `guess` is used in the `while` condition before it has been assigned a value - that's an error.

Regarding the main problem:

- In order to allow the user to *input more than 1 character* (i. e. up to two for a two-digit number), you can use a sufficiently sized character array. Of course you then have to account for a second character when checking *using "Isdigit"*. So e. g. replace

  > ```
  >                    scanf(" %s", &guess);
  >    
  >                if (isdigit(guess)==0)
  > ```

  with

  ```
              char s[2+1];    // +1 for string-terminating null character
              if (scanf(" %2s", s) < 1 || !isdigit(s[0]) || s[1] && !isdigit(s[1]))
  ```
- In order to convert the string in the array to an integer, you can simply use `atoi`:

  ```
                  guess = atoi(s);
  ```